# JavaScript - why the code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning JavaScript from tutorials [online](http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=js_lightbulb) but I couldn't get these two tasks work.I can't see what's wrong in my code....

This is intended to change a image into another when viewer clicks on it.

```
<script>
    function LightUp(){
        element = document.getElementById(myimage)
        if(element.src.match("eg_bulboff.gif")){
            element.src = "eg_bulbon.gif";
        }else{
            element.src = "eg_bulboff.gif";
        }
    }
</script>
<p>Click the bulb to light it up!</p>
<p><img id="myimage" onclick="LightUp()" src="eg_bulboff.gif"></p>
```

The code below is intended to change the text into red

```
<p id="demo4">Change my colour</p>
<script>
    function Red(){
        x = document.getElementById("demo4")
        x.stype.color = "#ff0000";
    }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="Red()">Click me</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a free tip that'll help you learn good JavaScript coding: don't use w3schools.

Comment: You are using `myimage` which will return undefined variable, so use quotes around that

Comment: Can you recommend any good sites? I need to learn Javascript within like 2 days for a school project ..

Comment: You're writing `stype`, you probably meant `Skype` ??

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and go through the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). If you want to learn more about event handling, check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! I'll check them out =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `myimage` a string.

```
element = document.getElementById('myimage');
```

You should also consider declaring your variables with `var` or they will end up being global variables.

Comment: to add... looks like in the 'Red()' function..
    x.stype.color = "#ff0000";
should be...
    x.style.color = "#ff0000";
maybe a copy/paste boo boo??

Comment: Thanks! That works. BTW I dont seem to see the difference between `x.stype.color = "#ff0000";` and `x.style.color = "#ff0000"; `i know its a silly question sorry lol

Comment: @Sue sty **p** e -> sty **l** e